# Memory efficient cartesian join in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have a large dataset of string ids, that can fit into memory on a single node in my spark cluster. The issue is that it consumes most of the memory for a single node.

These ids are about 30 characters long. For example:

```
ids
O2LWk4MAbcrOCWo3IVM0GInelSXfcG
HbDckDXCye20kwu0gfeGpLGWnJ2yif
o43xSMBUJLOKDxkYEQbAEWk4aPQHkm
```

I am looking to write to file a list of all of the pairs of ids. For example:

```
id1,id2
O2LWk4MAbcrOCWo3IVM0GInelSXfcG,HbDckDXCye20kwu0gfeGpLGWnJ2yif
O2LWk4MAbcrOCWo3IVM0GInelSXfcG,o43xSMBUJLOKDxkYEQbAEWk4aPQHkm
HbDckDXCye20kwu0gfeGpLGWnJ2yif,O2LWk4MAbcrOCWo3IVM0GInelSXfcG
# etc...
```

So I need to cross join the dataset on itself. I was hoping to do this on PySpark using a 10 node cluster, but it needs to be memory efficient.

Comment: How many records dataset contains? How much memory every node have? Do you use pure RDD or Dataframes API?

Comment: @Mariusz right now, this is in a text file on the master, but when I read it into a python list in memory it consumes about 80% of the 8GB of RAM. The list length is about 100M records. I can put the dataset in either an RDD or Dataframe.

Answer (score 13):

pySpark will handle your dataset easily and memory efficient but it will take time to process 10^8 * 10^8 records (this is estimated size of cross join result). See sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = spark.read.csv('input.csv', header=True, schema=StructType([StructField('id', StringType())]))
df.withColumnRenamed('id', 'id1').crossJoin(df.withColumnRenamed('id', 'id2')).show()
```